# jQuery custom content scroller - trigger scrollTop Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

### How to Trigger ScrollTop Event to make other plugins work with the custom content scroller

I need to get some plugins to work which use scroll and scrollTop events from jquery and javascript. Is it possible to trigger these events without rewriting the plugins?

About the Custom content scroller events i found this:
[custom content scroller #Events](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#callbacks-section)

If not do you have an idea how i could find a workaround?

Plugin: [Link to jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Answer (score 0):

**For jQuery**

```
$('.element').off('scroll').on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop == 0){
        console.log('ScrollTop');
    } else if (scrollTop + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
        console.log('ScrollBottom');
    }
});
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with my question. but anyway thank you for the answer